# How to create a global array with user defined length?

Tags: c, pthreads

I am trying to solve this problem with threads and I am required to use pipes with this aswell. I need to create N pipes and N threads, but in order to create N pipes which is ( int fd[N][2];) and be accessible through the thread function the pipes need to be global.

I have looked into using dynamic memory which I never used before, but could not figure out how to do it. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Dynamic memory is the right way to go. You'll almost certainly need to know how to do that sooner or later. So now would be a good time. Please show your best attempt and explain what specific problem you have.

Comment: Rafael Neocleous, you could define a global of say `int fd[100][2]` and simply limit user input to 100.  Later on, as your skills grow, switch to `int (*fd)[2] = malloc(sizeof *fd * N)`.

Answer (score 0):

> How to create a global array with user defined length?

Technically, you can't.  "Global" is not a C-language term, but what you mean is an object with external linkage, and the dimensions of an array that has external (or internal) linkage must be integer constant expressions.

Among the things you *can* do is to declare a pointer object with external linkage, and dynamically allocate space for it to point to, according to the user's specification.  You could access the allocated object via the pointer using the same syntax that you do for arrays.  Example:

**data.h**

```
// ...

extern int (*fd)[2];
extern int num_pipes;

// ...
```

**main.c**

```
// ...

// no "extern" in this one place:
int (*fd)[2];
int num_pipes;

int main(void) {
    // ... set num_pipes ...

    fd = malloc(num_pipes * sizeof(*fd));
    if (fd == NULL) {
        // TODO: handle allocation failure
    }

    // ...
}
```

**other.c**

```
#include "data.h"

int make_pipes() {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_pipes; i++) {
        int result = pipe(fd[i]);
        // ... error handling ...
    }
}
```